# Is there an include parameter for sentry/browser to include only specific files?

Tags: reactjs, sentry

I want to add sentry to my React widget. it's a Hotel Reservation widget and lots of hotels use it.I added @senty/browser to the project and now there is a problem whenever any error happens in their websites i receive an issue from sentry. but i don't want to get errors from their codes.

here's my simple Sentry config code:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser'

Sentry.init({
    dsn: SENTRY_DSN
})
```

I want a way to tell sentry only send errors from the widget scope ( only from some js files that belongs to the widget). Any help would be appreciated.

I searched and all i found was "beforeSend" function that will be called before sending the issue. but i couldn't figure it out. the data argument of beforeSend does not contain any usefull data for checking whether the error is from my code or not. and I don't know if it's possible to prevent sending issue inside beforeSend.

PS: the way that these hotels add the widget to their website is simple. they just have to add a script tag to the footer of their website (the built main.js of my project) and a div tag in wherever they want the widget to be placed (this div tag must have a specific ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this one:

```js
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

init({
  beforeSend(event, hint) {
    const error = hint.originalException;
    if (error && error.message && error.message.match(/database unavailable/i)) {
      event.fingerprint = ['database-unavailable'];
    }
    return event;
  }
});
```

[Gihtub issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2039)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to get the name of the file that contains the error?

Comment: Here more details https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/filtering/?platform=node

Comment: Thank you very much. I added event.stack.includes("file name here") to the if statement